# Membership rest and chang password in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, password-recovery, change-password

i want to change password manually and send password to my users but i got the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. what is wrong with my cods:
thank you:

```
        Random r = new Random();
        string code = r.Next(100000, 9999999).ToString();

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["****"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Count(ID) FROM RolInfo where username=@username", sqlconn);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);

        sqlconn.Open();
        int count = ((int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());


        sqlconn.Close();


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (count != 0)
        {

          Sendmail();

            MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser();
            u.ChangePassword(u.ResetPassword(), code);
        }
        else
        {
            lab_Message.Visible = true;
            lab_Message.Text = "This username is invalid.";
            lab_Message.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        }

    }
    else
    {
        lab_Message.Visible = true;
        lab_Message.Text = "Please enter your username.";
        lab_Message.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code...?... there is no GridView or call to any GridView in your current question.

Comment: @Darren: there is no gridview here!!! i got the username from a text box.

Comment: So why in your question "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. to idx of grid view" <-- Grid view? - Exactly what line does the error say there is the problem?

Comment: @Darren: thank you for mentioning that. it is for my membership. when object u came from membership user, it is null. why it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing in an argument to `Membership.GetUser();`

`Membership.GetUser();` Gets the currently-logged in user. As you're not logged in it will return `null`. If you were logged in it would return only you, and not your members.

If you want to get the user then you need to pass in their `username`. Like this:

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(TextBox1.Text);
```

**UPDATE**

You don't need to do a call to the SQL Database to check if the user exists.

you can do this instead.

```
   MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(TextBox1.Text);

   if (u != null){
      SendMail();
      u.ChangePassword(u.ResetPassword(), code);
   }else{
      lab_Message.Visible = true;
      lab_Message.Text = "This username is invalid.";
      lab_Message.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   }
```

By the way, the users password will NOT be set to `code` - this will get set to the users answer to their security question. `ResetPassword` resets the password to an automatically generated one.

See here for documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.resetpassword.aspx

Comment: thank for your answering. what do you mean by saying username from sql? if the input username is correct it is exist in sql.
is there any better way to change password ?

Comment: Edited my answer. You need to pass the "USERNAME" of the user who's password you want to change. Give me 2 minutes. I will make another edit.